# Property binding inside AfterViewInit is not affecting the view

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working with `Mapbox` in my Angular project and I need to show some information in my `component.html` from my `component.ts`.

I'm using `mat-vertical-stepper` where each step is a new `component`:

```
 <mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
      ...
      <mat-step [stepControl]="locationStepForm">
           <ng-template matStepLabel>Localização</ng-template>
           <app-location-step [locationStepForm]="locationStepForm"></app-location-step>
      </mat-step>
      ...
 </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

So, inside `locationStepForm` I have a Mapbox map. To get the map working I put its initialization inside the `AfterViewInit` method:

```
  @Input() locationStepForm: FormGroup;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const container = document.getElementById('map');

    if (container) {
      var map = new Mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.map.nativeElement, // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-51.186971, -29.1836891], // starting position, LNG/LAT
        zoom: 15 // starting zoom
      });
    }
  }
```

The problem is that at some point, I need to call a function to update a property so its value can be shown in the view via property binding.

```
  @Input() locationStepForm: FormGroup;

  latitude: number = 0;  

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const container = document.getElementById('map');

    if (container) {
      var map = new Mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.map.nativeElement, // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-51.186971, -29.1836891], // starting position, LNG/LAT
        zoom: 15 // starting zoom
      });

      geocoder.on('result', function (e) {
         geocoder.clear();
         this.updateLatitude(e.result.center[1]);
      }
    }
  }

  updateLatitude(latitude: number) {
     this.latitude = latitude;
  }
```

When `this.updateLatitude(e.result.center[1]);` is called, I get this error:

[image]

And if I access the property directly, **the information is not being shown** in my `component.html`.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...

    geocoder.on('result', function (e) {
        ...
        this.latitude = e.result.center[1];
    }
  }
```

And this is my component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="locationStepForm">

    <p class="m-l-10">
        <span class="text-header">Informe a localização</span>
    </p>

    <div id="geocoder" class="geocoder"></div>
    <div #mapElement id="map" class="map"></div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <span class="text-header">Local selecionado</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <span>Latitude: {{latitude}}</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <span>Longitude: {{longitude}}</span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Retornar</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext class="button-colored m-l-10">Avançar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an arrow function in this part:

```
  geocoder.on('result', (e) => { //here use arrow function
    geocoder.clear();
    this.updateLatitude(e.result.center[1]);
  }
```

Note that if you use `function` the reference to `this` is no longer the same.
If you would insist to use a `function` instead of a `arrow function` you should store a reference to `this` in a variable before the geocoder.on event.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const container = document.getElementById('map');
    var self = this;

    if (container) {
      var map = new Mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.map.nativeElement, // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-51.186971, -29.1836891], // starting position, LNG/LAT
        zoom: 15 // starting zoom
      });

      geocoder.on('result', function (e) {
         geocoder.clear();
         self.updateLatitude(e.result.center[1]);
      }
    }
  }
```